# why i get empty file after using os.popen copy function?

Tags: python, popen

```
    if os.path.exists("C:\Winusr\issue wintrace\west\Wintrace.log"):
        #shutil.copyfile("C:\Winusr\issue wintrace\west\Wintrace.log", "C:\Winusr\wintrace1.log")
        f = os.popen('copy C:\Winusr\issue wintrace\west\Wintrace.log C:\Winusr\wintrace1.log')
        print("success")
        f.close()   
    else:
        print("fail")
```

it can print"success", but the wintrace1.log file is empty and the last modified time also old time, means it didn't changed.

Answer (score 1):

```
    if os.path.exists("C:\Winusr\issue wintrace\west\Wintrace.log"):
    #shutil.copyfile("C:\Winusr\issue wintrace\west\Wintrace.log", "C:\Winusr\wintrace1.log")
    os.chdir("C:\Winusr\issue wintrace\west")
    f = os.popen('copy Wintrace.log wintrace1.log')
    print("success")
    print(f.readlines())
    f.close()
else:
    print("fail")
```

solved.